# Init scripts do not run on mongo container start

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to create a MongoDB replica set with a standalone instance running in docker to be able to work with multi-document transactions.

The problem is that the replica set is not initiated automatically, I always have to start it manually, so I can't run it in gitlab runner.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM mongo:4.2

RUN echo "rs.initiate({'_id':'rs0','members':[{'_id':0,'host':'127.0.0.1:27017'}]});" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js

RUN chmod u+x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js

RUN cat /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/replica-init.js

CMD [ "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
```

And here the docker-compose snippet:

```
  mongo:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/mongo/Dockerfile
    command: --replSet rs0
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

I put this script into docker-entrypoint-initdb.d so it should run automatically on first container start but it does not happen.

If I run the same initiate() command manually using mongo shell - it then works fine.

Any ideas on what I do wrong?

Comment: did you tried `docker-compose up --build` instead of `docker-compose up`?

Comment: yes, I even destroyed the image to clear the cache layers and rebuilt it - to no effect =(

Comment: you have both CMD in dockerfile and command in docker-compose. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: I guess, the one in the docker-compose can be removed. But still it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I have the same issue. If I add `rs.initiate(...)` into init script, it doesn't work. Although if I run same code after it started, it works fine. I figured out that only rs.initiate() doesn's work, other commands like `db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser` work well. Another observation is that after init scripts are done, I can see this log message `***** SERVER RESTARTED *****`. Maybe it has something to do with rs.initiate(...), wiping out its effect. Not sure though.

Comment: Please post if you have a solution.